Applying for a working holiday visa
I went to Australia and stayed for a month and did not work whilst I was there despite me having a working holiday visa. I now want to re apply for a working holiday visa but it is saying I had to have worked during the time I was there previously or I can not have this new visa. Is there a way of me getting this working holiday visa?

What was the reason for you not working while you had the visa?

If you obviously did not comply with the conditions of your previous visa of this type, it is highly unlikely you will be given another of the same type. Australia, and indeed most nations generally, take that rather seriously. Did you make sincere attempts to find work while you were there? Did you have employment opportunities lined up before you arrived? If you actually tried to follow the rules of this type of visa, but the economic reality just didn't support that when you turned up.... You should consult with a specialist/lawyer.

The Government of Australia lays out the conditions for getting a second working holiday visa.
Among the conditions are:

You must have completed 3 months of specified subclass 417 work

Presumably this is to prevent people from using Working Holiday visas when they are only wanting to do tourism.
You could attempt to consult with a lawyer to see if there is a way round this.
